# Why can't i get the proper output by this code?

Tags: c, output

I'm working on a problem that troubling me for a while. Still can't understand. It makes sense to change the type of `m`, but I still can't understand what `m` went through in this process. How does its value change?
Below is the code.

I've tried it on code blocks.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int m=5;
    m = (float)m / (2.0);//There, shouldn't m be 2.500000?
    printf("%f\n", m);
    printf("%0.2f\n",(float)m/2.0);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Expected result:

> ```
> 2.500000
> 1.25
> ```

Actual result:

> ```
> nan
> 1.00
> ```

Comment: please next time properly format your code. I did this for you now, from now on please do yourself.

Comment: @clockstream This call  printf("%f\n", m); has undefined behavior because there is used a wrong format conversion specifier %f with an object of the type int,

Comment: `m` has type `int`.  Assigning a `float` or `double` value to it doesn't change that - the value is converted to `int` before the assignment.  Variables in C never change their type.

Comment: An integer is an integer and a float is a float. If you attempt to store a float in an integer, the type of the variable doesn't magically change. Rather, all decimals will be dropped.

Comment: @bolov thank you very much. I am learning how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`m` is an `int`. So if you do `m = (float)m / (2.0);`, then even if `(float)m / (2.0)` is `2.5`, it will be truncated to be stored in `m` as `2`. So when you do this

```
printf("%f\n", m);
```

You have undefined behavior because it's an `int` and you say it's a `float`.

Later you do this

```
printf("%0.2f\n",(float)m/2.0);
```

and you get `1.0` because `m` was `2` and you divide it by `2.0`. You can get the expected output by changing the type of `m` to `float` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've understood it. while i have another question, when I run it on VC++, it'll get the answer: 0.000000  1.00. Is it means that nan is equal to 0.000000?

Comment: Not quite. Since the print line exhibits undefined behavior, anything can happen, there's no guarantee on what the result will be. It's common that the behavior will be different with a different compiler, on a different machine, or sometimes even when run multiple times with the same configuration. That's why undefined behavior is so problematic - sometimes everything seems to work, and then when it's important, it suddenly breaks.

Comment: If you are interested in knowing what NaN is in IEEE 754 (the floating point standard which your compiler most likely uses), you can read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#NaN).

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%f\n", m); // m is int
```

Nope. `"%f"` does not go with `int`.

Either use `"%d"` or convert the value

```
printf("%d\n", m);
printf("%f\n", (double)m);
```

Note that converting to `float` forces a second automatic conversion to `double`

```
printf("%f\n", (float)m); // convert twice
```